# How to auto-discover a lagging of time-series data in scikit-learn and classify using time-series data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, quantitative-finance

I currently have a giant time-series array with times-series data of multiple securities and economic statistics.

I've already written a function to classify the data, using sci-kit learn, but the function only uses non-lagged time-series data.

Is there a way, in Python, using sci-kit, to **automatically** lag all of these time-series to **find** what time-series (if any) tend to lag other data?

I'm working on creating a model using historic data to predict future performance.

Comment: Could you, please, a bit exemplify the intention? Automatic sounds as a bit super-ninja-on-steroids for quant-modelling and a cause-effect principle is in danger in these fields ( even Google had not so long ago presented a big "success" in having used TensorFlow to predict, but was caught to just do a **"peeking-into-future"** mistake and base their claims on an unfair benefit from a *"negative lag"* which will not work in real-world ... ), so due care is indeed a must here. >>> https://medium.com/@michalillich/how-google-s-financial-predictor-predicts-the-past-58dc4d644703#.qijgfrfjs

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which statistics (if any) tend to lead real world results and by how much they lead the data. I have a pre-existing model I'm working on improving by changing/adding additional inputs. I'm trying to find potential additional inputs for my model. I've built a classifier function using sci-kit to find potential new inputs, but it only classifies unlagged data. Unless I write a gigantic nested loop to lag each of the data one time period at a time (which would be extremely inefficient), I won't be able to see how lagged results correlates to stats data.

Comment: Yes, avoid any "external" for-loops. Attached please find an all-numpy solution working on a bit different grounds of feature-engineering tools in scikit-learn and having the all powers from pure-numpy tricks. Localhost CPU and RAM limits are not a hidden glass-ceiling to run into in this, so enjoy the ride.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>`TLDR` but a few QF gems put in between the lines for those who care</sup>

### Prologue:

<kbd>**"There is no dinner for free"**</kbd> so we will have to pay a cost for having the wished result, but **you know it is pretty worth doing it**, so, get advanced creativity, `numpy` utilities knowledge and `scikit-learn` tools ready and turn the volume button of imagination on max.

Next, do not expect the process to deliver results in just few seconds.

With an experience of AI/ML-hyperparameters' search job-schedules on example **`DataSETs`** spanning just about `X.shape ~ ( 400, 200000 )`, the best-generalising ML-engine hyperparametrisation crossvalidation takes regularly several days on a distributed multi-processing cluster.

> **As a bonus for directing further Quant research efforts:**
> a sample from a similar feature-engineering research, with **`LDF()/GDF()`** indcators about **varying predictive power of respective features** elaborated into an **`extendedDataSET`**:
> as written below, one may realise that
> just the **top 1. feature** is responsible for 43% per se
> and the **next 27. features** account for +17%
> and the **"rest" 360+ features** added the remaining 40% into decisions as importances report
>   <sub>(
>  individual feature and pre-lagging detail$ are not publi$hed here for obviou$ rea$on$
> and are free to be discussed separately
> )</sub>

```
|>>> aFeatureImportancesMAP_v4( loc_PREDICTOR, X_v412 )

 ID.|LDF( fI ) | GDF|HUMAN_READABLE_FEATURE_NAME[COL] min()     | MAX()    | var()
 ___|__________|____|___________________________[___]___________|__________|____________
    |          |    |                           [   ]           |          |
  0. 0.4360231 | 43%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxxCE [216] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  1. 0.0464851 | 48%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_0 [215] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  2. 0.0104704 | 49%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [251] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  3. 0.0061596 | 49%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [206] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  4. 0.0055069 | 50%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [203] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  5. 0.0053235 | 50%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [212] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  6. 0.0050404 | 51%| ________f_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_7 [261] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  7. 0.0049998 | 52%| ________f_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_7 [253] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  8. 0.0048721 | 52%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [113] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
  9. 0.0047981 | 52%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [141] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 10. 0.0043784 | 53%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [142] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 11. 0.0043257 | 53%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [129] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 12. 0.0042124 | 54%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [144] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 13. 0.0041864 | 54%| ________f_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_8 [260] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 14. 0.0039645 | 55%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [140] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 15. 0.0037486 | 55%| ________f_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_8 [252] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 16. 0.0036820 | 55%| ________f_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_8 [268] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 17. 0.0036384 | 56%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [108] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 18. 0.0036112 | 56%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [207] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 19. 0.0035978 | 56%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [132] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 20. 0.0035812 | 57%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [248] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 21. 0.0035558 | 57%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [130] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 22. 0.0035105 | 57%| _______f_Kxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [283] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 23. 0.0034851 | 58%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [161] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 24. 0.0034352 | 58%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [250] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 25. 0.0034146 | 59%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [199] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 26. 0.0033744 | 59%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [ 86] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 27. 0.0033624 | 59%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [202] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 28. 0.0032876 | 60%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [169] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 ...
 62. 0.0027483 | 70%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_8 [117] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 63. 0.0027368 | 70%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [ 85] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 64. 0.0027221 | 70%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [211] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 ...
104. 0.0019674 | 80%| ________f_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [273] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
105. 0.0019597 | 80%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_6 [ 99] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
106. 0.0019199 | 80%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [104] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 ...
169. 0.0012095 | 90%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [181] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
170. 0.0012017 | 90%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [  9] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
171. 0.0011984 | 90%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_4 [185] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
172. 0.0011926 | 90%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [ 19] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 ...
272. 0.0005956 | 99%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [ 33] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
273. 0.0005844 | 99%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [127] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
274. 0.0005802 | 99%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [ 54] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
275. 0.0005663 | 99%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_3 [ 32] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
276. 0.0005534 | 99%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 [ 83] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
 ...
391. 0.0004347 |100%| __________xxxxxxxxxxxxx_2 [ 82] min:  ... | MAX: ... | var():  ...
```

**So rather plan & reserve a bit more vCPU-cores capacities**,
than to expect it to run such search on a laptop just during a forthcoming lunchtime...

---

### Let's have a working plan

the intended **`auto-find`** service, due to many reasons, is not a part of `scikit-learn`, however, the goal is achievable.

We will use the following adaptation steps, that will allow us to make it work:

1. we'll rely on **`scikit-learn`** abilities to search for a best tandem of a [`learner` + `hyperparameters`] **for a well-defined AI/ML problem**
2. we'll rely on **`numpy`** powers for obvious reasons to support `scikit-learn` phase
3. we'll rely on rather a proper `scikit-learn` AI/ML-engine processing & proces-controls ( `pipeline`, `GridSearchCV` et al ), which are by far better optimised on low-level performance for such massive-scale-attacks, than to try to depend on an "externally" ordinated **`for`**-looping ( which loses all the valuable cache/data-locality advances ) and is known to be of a remarkable performance disadvantage.
4. we'll substitute the wished autodiscovery by a fast, one-step, a-priori `DataSET` adaptation
5. we'll let `scikit-learn` decide **( quantitatively indicate )** which pre-lagged features, artificially synthesised into compound `DataSET` elaborated in [4] have finally the best predictive powers

---

### [4] `DataSET` adaptation with smart `numpy` aids:

Your `DataSET` consists of an unspecified count of TimeSeries-data. For each such, you assume some pre-lagging may have better predictive powers, that you would like to find ( quantitatively support the selection of such, for the final ML-predictor ).

So let's first construct for each TimeSerie **`DataSET[i,:]`** in the source-part of the `DataSET` an extended part of the `DataSET`, which contains the respectively pre-lagged versions of this TimeSerie:

```
>>> def generate_TimeSERIE_preLAGs( aTimeSERIE, pre_lag_window_depth ):
...     #
...     # COURTESY & THANKS TO:
...     #                     Nicolas P. Rougier, INRIA
...     #             Author: Joe Kington / Erik Rigtorp
...     #
...     shape   = ( aTimeSERIE.size - pre_lag_window_depth + 1,
...                 pre_lag_window_depth
...                 )
...     strides = ( aTimeSERIE.itemsize,
...                 aTimeSERIE.itemsize
...                 )
...     return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided( aTimeSERIE,
...                                             shape,
...                                             strides = strides
...                                             )
...
>>> xVECTOR = np.arange( 10 )
>>>
>>> pre_laggz_on_xVECTOR = generate_TimeSERIE_preLAGs( xVECTOR, 4 )
>>>
>>> pre_laggz_on_xVECTOR
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [5, 6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>>
```

With such extended ( wider, and you know that a lot ) **but static** `extendedDataSET`, containing now both the original `TimeSERIE` vector and all the wished-to-test pre-lagged versions thereof, your ML-search starts.

**Phase `[1.A]`**
Initially use `scikit-learn` tools for the best feature-selection supporting your hypothesis
+
**Phase `[1.B]`**
next start hyperparameter optimisation for the best cross-validation results supporting a maximum generalisation ability of the learner.

The phase `[1.B]`, naturally ought to run on a sub-set of the `extendedDataSET` ( as was intentionally extended for the sake of `scikit-learn` evaluation in feature-selection-phase `[1.A]` ).

---

### Epilogue:
 <kbd>Memento mori:</kbd> Quants do not like this ... but

For the sake of your further interests in TimeSeries analyses & quantitative modelling, [you might be interested in the **best answer on this** >>>](http://www.quantumforquants.org/question/can-clique-analysis-tell-us-something-new-about-time-series/)

[image]

Correlation does not imply Causation, so even more care is needed in making decisions to be executed ( paper can always handle much more, than the markets :o) ).

Comment: OP has already rejected an answer that involved not getting dinner for free. (But I enjoyed your writeup.)

Comment: Sorry about my choice of words... I guess after a 16+ hour workday my ability to express my thoughts specifically tends to go down the drain. "Automatically" was probably not the best choice.... I feel the snark, however, was unwarranted....

Comment: There is no need to feel sorry for a word-selection. You have decided to design a quite powerfull tool and the complications are common along your further paths of discovery. Wishing you good luck and perseverance on that & hope you enjoyed the few cents and the story above.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class InsertLags(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Automatically Insert Lags
    """
    def __init__(self, lags):
        self.lags = lags

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        original_cols=list(range(len(X[0,:])))
        for lag in self.lags:
            X_lagged=pd.DataFrame(X[:,original_cols]).shift(lag).as_matrix()
            X=np.concatenate((X,X_lagged), axis=1)
        return X
```

Then test it

```
add_lags=InsertLags([1,2,3])

test=np.array([[1,3,5,7,9],
      [2,4,6,8,10]]).T

test

add_lags.fit_transform(test)
```

This should create a sklearn transformer that automatically creates lags. If you want, you can make original_cols a part of the initialization function of the class so that you can selectively lag variables.

Answer (score 2):

No. there is not a way, in Python, using sci-kit, to **automatically** lag all of these time-series to find what time-series (if any) tend to lag other data. **You'll have to write some code**.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Even the promises of the new age of **Quantum Computing will not bring any such dinner for free**, as reported in a bit longer story posted below, in [Epilogue] section >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/37214127/3666197

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`numpy.roll()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).  Don't forget to erase the elements which wrapped around, e.g. you don't want `[6,7,1,2,3,4,5]` but `[NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: This would involve having to loop through each of the securities and run a regression/classification for each given amount of lag... am looking for a pre-existing library that can do this more efficiently.